# Trouble understanding UriMatcher Syntax

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I've done a lot of reading on the subject but I can't find anything on what these symbols, `*, #`, are meant to be/represent.

If they're used as a placeholder for something, like SqLite's `?`, then what are they replacing? Also, if all you're doing is matching Uri's, then whats the purpose of having this cryptic notation?

If I wanted to return a list, object or anything else, why wouldn't I just name the constant with something readable and give it an arbitrary value and go on from there?

E.g.

```
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people", PEOPLE);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#", PEOPLE_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones", PEOPLE_PHONES);
```

into

```
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people", PEOPLE);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people_id", PEOPLE_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people_phones", PEOPLE_PHONES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for example to delete an entry of my database with a specific id.

```
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse(NoteProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + id);
context.getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);

// URI Matcher
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, NOTE_BASE_PATH + "/#", NOTE_WITH_ID);

// delete
String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
rowsDeleted = db.delete(NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME, NoteEntry._ID + "=" + id, null);
```

- *: Matches a string of any valid characters of any length.
- #: Matches a string of numeric characters of any length.

An `URI` represents a path to a resource and that is what you access with an `ContentProvider`. So I think that `URI` is best suited in this case.

> A content URI is a URI that identifies data in a provider. Content
>   URIs include the symbolic name of the entire provider (its authority)
>   and a name that points to a table or file (a path). The optional id
>   part points to an individual row in a table.